# Run bash script that makes a folder based on python scriptname

Tags: python, bash

I have a question about running a bash script in a python file. First, let me explain the situation. I have multiple python files: for each city in Mali, I am able to create a weather forecast in python (therefore is have created multiple python files: e.g. gao.py, bamba.py, etc.) One of the steps in each python file, is to run a bash script that creates audiofiles in .wav format, and places them in a folder /converted. Now, my question the following:

How do I change the bash script in such a way, that when gao.py is running, a folder /converted/gao will be created, and when for example bamba.py is running, a folder converted/bamba is created?

This is the current bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d converted/gao ]
then
 mkdir converted/gao;
fi;
```

However, when I run the script above, each city will places his files in converted/gao, which is not what I want. I hope somebody knows how to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you already tried using os module,  
os.mkdir(path) will create folder at runtime.

Comment: Shouldn't the name of the city be an argument to the bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use __ file__ for accessing the filename of script in python. And then pass it as argument to bash script. After that access the argument in bash script using $1.
as following samples:

Python Script hello.py

```
import os

script_filename = __file__
# function to execute the shell script
os.system("./bashfile.sh {}".format(script_filename))
```

Sample Bash Script bashfile.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

script_name=$1
# now use the script_name as you like in your script.
echo $script_name
```

Comment: Hmm, I try to run the two code snippets, but terminal gives me the following error:sh: ./test.sh: Permission denied

Comment: `chmod 755 test.sh`  give execute permission to file